# Setting up IGeoProcessor2 object in .NET (C#)?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net

I'm wondering if I'm instantiating a new class with the `IGeoProcessor2` object correctly. It's working the way I have it now, but I feel like there's something else I should be doing so I don't have to turn "Embed Interop Types" in the Properties window to False. I'm working with ArcObjects 10.5, ArcGIS 10.5, and Visual Studio 2015.

This is the code I have to instantiate a new geoprocessing object:

```
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
```

If I leave the Esri.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing assembly's "Embed Interop Types" property on "True", I get a squiggly red line under `GeoProcessorClass`. If I set it to "False", the squiggly goes away and everything works as expected. The same thing also happens with the ESRI.ArcGIS.System assembly when I use this code:

```
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
```

If I were to set the "Embed Interop Types" to false for the System assembly then the squiggly under `VarArrayClass` goes away and everything works great.

Is this something everyone has to do to get their code to work, or am I missing something that allows me to keep "Embed Interop Types" as "True"?

I am using `IGeoProcessor2` instead of `GeoProcessor` because I am running a custom tool out of a custom toolbox, so I cannot switch to `GeoProcessor`. For whatever reason, I cannot get it to work with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'Embed Interop Types' is set to true then omit the 'Class' at the end of the type.

```
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArray();
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessor() as IGeoProcessor2;
```

Comment: Hm, when I do, I get "cannot implicitly convert type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessor' to ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" warning. This only occurs for the GeoProcessor, the VarArray does work when I remove the class.

Comment: You just need to cast the new object to IGeoProcessor2. Some objects have implicit conversions others do not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new at this. `IGeoProcessor2 gp = (IGeoProcessor2) new GeoProcessor();` worked. (I just saw you updated your answer, the "as" looks like a much cleaner way to type it. Great!)